# How to get many issues with Jira REST API?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

New to REST API, and struggling a little.

I learned recently from [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-get-Jira-issue-id-from-issue-key/qaq-p/1156675) and [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/REST-API-to-fetch-Jira-issue-id-of-a-particular-commit-in/qaq-p/1471382) that I can receive a JSON describing an issue by calling a REST API of the form `<JIRA_BASE_URL>/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}`, e.g.:

```
curl -s -X GET -u super_user:super_password https://jira.server.com/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-12
```

**Is there a way I can query many issues at once if I have a list of issue-ids, e.g. `["TEST-12", "TEST-13", "TEST-14"]`?**

I'm specifically interested in getting the summary field of each issue in my list of issue-ids. I.e. I'm trying to create a map of `[issue-id:summary]`. I currently do this by invoking the above `curl` command in a loop for each issue-id in my list. But I observe that this takes a long time, and I wonder if performance might be improved if there's a way to do a "bulk get" -- if such a feature exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the [JQL Search API endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-3-search-get) a try:

```
https://jira-url/rest/api/latest/search?fields=summary&jql=key%20in%20(TEST-12,%20TEST-13)
```

The `fields` parameter limits the fields returned, and the `jql` parameter lists out an array of the issue keys you'd like to retrieve.

The response looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 2,
    "issues": [
        {
            ...
            "key": "TEST-12",
            "fields": {
                "summary": "TEST-12 Summary"
            }
        },
        {
            ...
            "key": "TEST-13",
            "fields": {
                "summary": "TEST-13 Summary"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```